# Asymptotic estimate: is this solution correct?

Tags: combinatorics

The problem states: For an array nxn filled with unique integers {1, 2, ... , n^2} one can choose n tiles, each from a separate row and column, such that among the chosen integers there is no 4-element arithmetic sequence, if n is big enough. (Think of the chosen tiles as rooks on some nxn chessboard, none of the rooks can attack each other).

Solution: There are n! ways to choose n tiles from the nxn array (trivial). Now it is easy to see that every 4-element arithmetic sequence is determined by its smallest 2 numbers. We can choose the first number max n^2 times, and the second one max (n^2)/4 times. Thus the number if 4-element arithmetic sequences is O((n^4)/4). Now having prechosen 4 numbers, the rest can be chosen in (n-4)! ways. Because lim_n->inf (n4 (n-4)! /4 )/n! =(1/4)lim_n->inf n3 /(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) =1/4 so for sufficiently large n then there are more ways of choosing n squares than there ways to choose that contains 4 element sequence.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: First, pls format using mathjax as suggested.  As for your proof, I would take issue with two aspects: (1) the notation $O(n^4 / 4)$: the big $O()$ notation already subsumes any constant, so $O(n^4/4)$ and $O(n^4)$ are the same thing.  (2) I don't think you have fully justified the crucial $1/4$ factor.  Why can the second number be picked "max $n^2/4$ times"?  I can accept $1/3$ (and of course that doesn't change the conclusion) but even then I think you needed more justification.